# In pandas splitting the column on question mark (?)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with the value as below (mix of values in a column with ? and without ?):

/a/b/c?abc=0

d/e/f

1. I just need the rows that contains "?"
   then,
2. split this row using the "?", so that I get the output as /a/b/c as one column and anything after as other column

I have tried as below :

data['url'].str.contains("?") ==> for getting only rows contianing "?"

data['url'].str.split('?')[1] ==> then splitting on "?"

But this does not work.

could you help?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for get values after `?` with escape by `\` because special regex character and `$` for end of string:

```
data['new'] = data['url'].str.extract('\?(.*)$')
print (data)
            url    new
0  /a/b/c?abc=0  abc=0
1         d/e/f    NaN
```

Your solution working if escape `?`, because not exist second splitted value second row is `NaN`:

```
data['new'] = data['url'].str.split('\?').str[1]
print (data)
            url    new
0  /a/b/c?abc=0  abc=0
1         d/e/f    NaN
```

Comment: How do I filter the rows that only contains "?"

Comment: @Vicky - use `df = data[data['url'].str.contains("\?")]`